# Send and echo with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sorry if my question has been asked before, i tryed to seach but not answers (OR didn't understand the answer).

I have a link, and i like to get the value using AJAX, here is an exemple with PHP

HOME

```
<a href="page.php?value=3">Go</a>
```

PAGE

```
 $getValue = $_GET['value'];
 echo $getValue;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)** to perform ajax get

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href="page.php?value=3"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $.get("page.php",{value:3},function(data){
           alert(data);
        });
    });
});

</script>
<a href="page.php?value=3">Go</a>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php
 $getValue = $_GET['value'];
 echo $getValue;
?>
```

1. Include jQuery library.
2. Wrap your code within [**`$(document).ready(function(){ })`**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler, in order to bind even after dom element is loaded.
3. Use [**`preventDefault()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method to prevent browser default action on the event.
4. Use [**`click()`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for listening click event.
5. At last use [**`$.get()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for Ajax get.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer this kind of question.

Comment: this seems a joke, right ? I assume that i'm really zero in Ajax, and i don't think this answer is pretty cool, where do you put $.get("page.php",{value:3},function(data){
   alert(data);
}); ? header ? body ? need full instructions.

Comment: It's amazing to make no effort when asking a question and yet  be so ungrateful receiving an (actually pretty complete) answer.

Comment: @PranavCBalan i did as you said, when i click on the link (go) i see a pop up showing the linked page source code

Comment: `alert(data);` , will show the data in a popup box . the variable `data` contains the response.

Comment: Thanks @PranavCBalan i only need now to send a PHP Value, is this correct ? it's not working.... function getData() { $.post('page.php', { offset : offset, value : <?php echo $value;?>, }},(jQuery); ------ however if i type value : 1, it works, i like it to be dynamic, from DB

Answer (score 1):

With pure Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // put the xmlhttp.responseText in your html element
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "page.php?value=3", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.php",
    data: { value: 3 },
    context: document.body,
    success: function(){
      $(this).addClass("done");
    }
});
```

the default method in jquery is GET, but you can change this, for more jquery info see this page https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery ajax to do so

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "page.php",
  data: { value: 3}
});
```

page.php

```
<?php
 $getValue = $_GET['value'];
 echo $getValue;
?>
```